# Quantreg `summary.rq` takes too long to give results

Tags: r, summary, quantreg

I have a data set (`joined`) of 730,099 observations and 16 variables, to which I applied a quantile regression model using the following code:

```
library(quantreg)

taus <- c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9)

res <- rq(Deprivation~Age+Education+Gender+Size+Employed+Children+Condition+Milieu+DwellingSize+Ownership+
            DwellingType+Region, tau = taus, data=joined, method = "fn")
```

However, when I try to create the summary using the `summary` function, it takes a very long time to give results (this is my second day waiting for results). I tried different options; `se = "nid"`, `se = "iid"`, `se = "boot"`, `se = "conquer"`, and `bsmethod = "BLB"`, but they either don't work, or keep running indefinitely. Any suggestions as to how to make `summary` run faster would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you `debug(quantreg:::summary.rq)` and step through to see which step(s) is/are slow?